# Помощь с преобразованием данных с базы в многомерные массивы

Tags: массивы, php, mysql

```
menu_id           menu_title                  menu_parent
1                    Компьютеры                    0
2                    Ноутбуки                      0
3                    Разное                        0
4                    Компьютеры 1                  1     
5                    Компьютеры 2                  1  
6                    Компьютеры 1.1                4  
7                    Ноутбуки 1                    2
8                    Ноутбуки 2                    2
```

Из этой выборки нужно сделать многомерный массив:

```
Компьютеры
    Компьютеры 1
        Компьютеры 1.1
    Компьютеры 2
Ноутбуки
    Ноутбуки 1
    Ноутбуки 2
Разное
```

Вложенность не ограничена. Подскажите пару идей как достинуть такого вида. Спасибо.

Answer (score 2):

В Вашем случае мне кажется лучше использовать [Nested Sets](http://www.getinfo.ru/article610.html)